# How can I find a Server I was already on?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Yesterday, I found a cool Minecraft server. Unfortunately, I do not remember its name. How can I find this server again? Is there a list of already visited servers?

Answer (score 1):

If you used **Direct Connect** to join the server, you can launch the game and the last address used to connect will be there.